# Coded UI - Edit uimap.uitest before test run

Tags: c#, testing, coded-ui-tests, uitest

I have a requirement where I need to change window titles before executing a test case from Coded UI.
The window title remains same except that a part of it must be replaced by another string. Eg: [Main Window - abc] need to be updated as [Main Window - xyz].

Currently I have built an app which finds and replaces the text in .uitest files[as .uitest is just an xml.]

Can somebody let me know if there is a way to do it inside my test code itself.
Like update the titles and then execute the case.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Update this in your constructor:

```
this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Main Window - abc";
```

To this:

```
this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Main Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
```

Unless you are referring to this line of code that gets inserted if you are using the Coded UI Test Builder to generate your object mappings:

```
this.WindowTitles.Add("Main Window - abc");
```

In which case you can just delete that line of code. It is unnecessary and not used in finding window objects.